# How do I run .launch files?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of the files that I have from downloading ROS have .launch file extensions. I was wondering what this means, but I cannot find anything through Google or Wikipedia. Also, is roslaunch the only way to run .launch files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10486/how-do-i-run-.launch-files?/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.launch is simply a [roslaunch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch) file. It is an XML file which specifies nodes to launch and parameters to assign to them. It's an easy way to avoid typing "rosrun ... " over and over again when you need to launch many nodes in a particular system.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-05**:
I don't actually need another way to run them; it would have simply made things a bit easier.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-05**:
I don't believe so. Why do you need another way?

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-05**:
Is there another way to run them, or is roslaunch the only way?